# MySQL are my indexes good?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am wondering if my Index setup is correct in MySQL (InnoDB). I am not an expert on indexes but from what I read about them I *hope* I understood well. To make sure I am right, I would like to ask members of this community.

**I have two tables:**

> 1) "users", with fields: id, fullname, status, sex,...
>
> 2) "orders", with fields id, id_user, order_date

When I locate an order I link it through "id_user" to table "users" (id).

There are around 1 mio of users and "status" field in "orders" can have 10 different values.

**Primary Index**

I have a PRIMARY index on field "users:id", which I believe it is useful when I do queries like "SELECT FROM users USE INDEX (PRIMARY) WHERE (id=33)" and when I will link order to certain user. Similar index I have in table "orders". This is probably ok.

## The problem

Because I will search orders by their status and then link it to correct user, I created an index on two fields in table "orders":

> Index name "status__id_user", fields (status, id_user)

My query to list new orders and link it with right users looks like:

> SELECT * FROM orders USE INDEX (status__id_user), users USE INDEX (PRIMARY) WHERE (orders.status='new') AND (orders.id_user = users.id)

## Question

Do I need index on two fields just because I am linking to users table with field "id_user"? Does it speed up things or it would be same if my index in "orders" table is just by field "status"? In that case 100,000 records would be selected and then MySQL would link it to "users" table to get correct users.

My question is if my index helps in anyway to speed up this part of the query:

> AND (orders.id_user = users.id)

Thank you!

Comment: basic rule of thumb: any field used in a "decision" context should have an index on it. that's anything used in a `where`, `join`, `order by`, etc...

Comment: The initial field list puts the `status` field in the `user` table. I assume that is incorrect?

Comment: Do **never** say the optimizer which index to use. you lose. the optimizer is better. change your query that the optimizer takes the best index. check it with EXPLAIN SELECT your query

Comment: From what I read, if you do where by two fields, it make sense to create 2-column index such as (surname, firstname) for example. Are you saying I should never use USE INDEX (...)? What is the purpose of that them? I mean, if I would be sure which index is best it would make sense. What if optimizer doesn't know? Hmmm

Comment: Marc B, what if WHERE would need one index and ORDER BY would need to sort by something completely else? For example: SELECT * FROM users WHERE (name LIKE '') ORDER BY status?  Should I have one index by two fields or what kind or indexes i need in such case? Would MySQL use two indexes for this query (index by name and index by status)?

Answer (score 2):

Write the query this way:

```
SELECT *
    FROM orders
    JOIN users  ON orders.id_user = users.id
    WHERE orders.status='new'
```

Do not specify what indexes to use.

Starting with the `WHERE` clause, it looks like this *might* be useful:  `INDEX(status)`.  But since "status" sounds like a "flag" with low cardinality, the optimizer *may* decide to ignore the index and simply do a table scan.  *This is OK.*  It is OK because it is faster to do a table scan than bounce between an index and the data, when the index is not very selective.  In any case, leave the decision up to the Optimizer.

Now that it is dealing with `orders`, it needs to `JOIN` to `users`.  The only way to do that is to have an index on `id`.  That name ("id") implies that it might be the `PRIMARY KEY`, is it?  (Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)

[*Index cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

The other query you mentioned should be written

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=33
```

And, as already discussed, the index (`PRIMARY KEY`?) on `id` is the right thing.

There is no advantage (for the given `SELECTs`, at least) for `INDEX(status, id_user)`.  Your select includes all columns (`*`); it it had fetched only `id_user`, then such an index would be "covering", and have some advantage.